# Getstream - Filter the activities by custom fields

Tags: getstream-io

I add many activities to my user feed. How to filter the activities by "category":"tech"?

this is my activity example:

person.add_activity
({
        "actor": "user",
        "verb": "post",
        "object": "post12",
        "foreign_id": "user:123",
        "message": "hi everyone",
        "category":"tech"
})

Answer (score -1, accepted):

unfortunately we don't support filtering on reads. The way most customers handle this is by creating a feed for each thing you want to filter on, then follow/unfollow based on whether or not you want to see those items in your feed. For instance, if your user follows fruit, you create feeds for apples, bananas and pears and have the user feed follow all 3. If they want to filter on only apples, you unfollow bananas and pears.

Comment: But this would have a side effect, right? I can't just do this on the fly, temporarily, on a specific view?

Would it work like: imagine a filter with checkboxes for users, in admin view. admin (aggregated) checks one user (follow), when i refresh the view or whatever, i see the last 300 activities immediately from user feed which admin just followed.

Comment: and then i can use this real-time-ish follow/unfollow procedure for a filtering functionality? imagine a typical admin dashboard with filters and stuff.

Comment: This will work and will be infrastructure intensive. So if you're on a standard plan might blow through updates quickly. If you're on enterprise, will have no effect. But there will be a small delay due to the unfollows, maybe 100ms or so. Hopefully people don't go crazy with the checking and unchecking.

Comment: @ScottLasica: any changes on this?